# R Character and Date Type Comparison

Tags: r

I'm wondering why does date of character type still act as a Date type in R.

For example:

```
x <- "2020-01-15"
y <- "2020-01-29"

x < y // *returns true*
x >= 2020 // *returns true*

Is there some auto type conversion in the background?
```

Answer (score 2):

No, they are evaluated as character, and you can compare characters as well.

```
'a' < 'b'
# [1] TRUE
```

**Note:**

```
100 < 20
# [1] FALSE

'100' < '20'
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

**Strings are compared [lexicographicaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) in R.**

So the only reason `x < y` is because the second last character of `x` is `1`, but in `y` it's `2`, so therefore `x` is smaller than `y`.

---

For string comparison of substrings of a string, i.e. `2020` is a substring of `2020-01-05`, the longer string would be the bigger string in lexicographical comparison. Therefore obviously the second case gives `TRUE`.