# update column based on duplicated rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a `df` as below

```
df <- data.frame(col = c("Acer laurinum", "Acer laurinum"),
                 author = c("", "Hassk."),
                 value = c(1,1))

df
                     col    author value1 value2
1          Acer laurinum                1      2
2          Acer laurinum    Hassk.      1      3
3 Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.      0      1
4 Acronychia pedunculata                0      0
```

I would like to update the `author` column saying that if I found any duplicated rows in `col` column, then the blank cell of `author` associated with the value (i.e. `Acer laurinum`) will be updated to `Hassk.` And the `value` must be retained.

- Desired output

```
                     col    author value1 value2
1          Acer laurinum    Hassk.      1      2
2          Acer laurinum    Hassk.      1      3
3 Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.      0      1
4 Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.      0      0
```

Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::mutate` with `max`:

```
df %>% group_by(col) %>%
   mutate(author=max(author))
```

Output:

```
  col                    author    value1 value2
  <chr>                  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Acer laurinum          Hassk.         1      2
2 Acer laurinum          Hassk.         1      3
3 Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.      0      1
4 Acronychia pedunculata (L.) Miq.      0      0
>
```

Comment: Could you explain how `max` works on a `chr` column? I tried with `min` but it returned an emply string as output.

Comment: @KarthikS If you compare, `Hassk.` is bigger than `''`, since it's a empty string, it would be always less than non-empty strings, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388726/r-character-and-date-type-comparison/69388876#69388876) out

Comment: thank you, I just read about `max` and `min` function that I have used for this thing

Comment: @U12-Forward sorry, can I ask one question, what if I have one more row, and now the `col` added with NA NA. Can we turn it to NA within the function `max` ?

Comment: oh No, my bad sorry, no worries

Comment: @Anh :) The `max` function is set to `na.rm=FALSE` by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Base option 1:
df$author <- with(df, ave(author, col, FUN = max))

# Base option 2:
transform(
  with(
    df,
    replace(df, df == "", NA_character_)[
      order(col, author, decreasing = TRUE),
    ]
  ),
  author = na.omit(author)[cumsum(!(is.na(author)))]
)[row.names(df),]
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(col = c("Acer laurinum", "Acer laurinum", "Acronychia pedunculata", 
"Acronychia pedunculata"), author = c("", "Hassk.", "(L.) Miq.", 
""), value1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0), value2 = c(2, 3, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```